# How to know Who's online on Facebook

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am making an iphone app in which i required the functionality to get notify when the particular users get online. There is an app on itune's Who's online, that uses this functionality, but i don't know how can i achieve this. Is there any API provided for it by Facebook developers or what. Does anyone know anything about this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the official Facebook iOS SDK:

[Facebook iOS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/)

Comment: That i have seen already, do you know any specific link related to the problem.